# Chop wood, carry water: why?

Tags: zen, daily-life

A very famous, so famous it may be apocryphal, zen quote says:

> Before Enlightenment chop wood carry water, after Enlightenment, chop
>   wood carry water.

What does this mean? Specifically, is the discourse saying that time without effort is wasted time?

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, I am not a well-versed student of Zen ... or Buddhism for that matter. However, I will offer my interpretation: Before you achieve enlightenment you will have to do chores associated with everyday living. Then, even after becoming enlightened, you will still have to do the same chores - becoming enlightened does not remove the need to deal with everyday things.